# Why my Like button not working : 'URL could not be liked because it's been blocked'

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a website, with 3 like buttons per article, and everything was fine 4-5 mounth until yesterday, I noticed that my like buttons don't work, when I click on it I get this error: 'URL could not be liked because it's been blocked'.

Comment: You should try [contacting Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal)

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the header of your page:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="insert_fb_page_id_here" />
```

Should do the trick. :) Worked for me.

EDIT: It might just be that your site is indeed blocked by facebook due to spam reports or other reason. Contact [these](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) guys to have it reopened

Comment: You should also try [contacting Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal)

Comment: Didn't see your comment before I edited. You are right obviously. :)

Comment: Now its a better answer :P Maxed out my votes today already - You'll get an upvote from me tomorrow :)

Comment: With meta property not worked, I contacted Fb developers, I hope to resolve as quickly because I receive complaints from visitors

Comment: It work! My like buttons work now, thanks guys. However, after I click like, I need to confirm this. It's a old problem and I hoped that with time this confirm link will disappear, but I have some weeks and problem still persist

Comment: Good! Now tell us what you did. Did you contact facebook support?

Comment: Yes,I contacted facebook support and today everything is fine, except confirm link.